# Custom environments with MARLlib

Tags: ray, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I've been going through the MARLlib documentation, and though they mention it's a mix of Ray and RLlib ([link](https://marllib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/intro.html)), I'm not quite sure if it supports custom environments like RLlib does.

I haven't come across any information regarding this. Has anyone here had experience with MARLlib and custom environments?